# CurrencyTextBox does not format the text on first load

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm creating `CurrencyTextBox` for windows application using C#. It's almost done, but I'm getting a problem when the `CurrencyTextBox` displayed its text. It is not in currency formatted. For example:

> 20000 it should be displayed as $20,000.00

In order to be displayed as $20,000.00 I must call the formatting code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currencyTextBox1.Value = 20000;
    currencyTextBox1.Text = currencyTextBox1.Value.ToString("C");
}
```

Is there another way to simplify this problem?

Below is the code for CurrencyTextBox:

```
public class CurrencyTextBox : TextBox
{
    private decimal _value = 0;

    public CurrencyTextBox()
    {
        base.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    }

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEnter(e);

        this.Text = _value.ToString();

        if (this.Text == "0")
            this.Clear();

        this.SelectionStart = this.Text.Length;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);

        NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
        string decimalSeparator = numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        string groupSeparator = numberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator;
        string negativeSign = numberFormatInfo.NegativeSign;

        // Workaround for groupSeparator equal to non-breaking space 
        if (groupSeparator == ((char)160).ToString())
        {
            groupSeparator = " ";
        }

        // Allows only numbers, decimals and control characters
        if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != decimalSeparator[0])
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyChar == decimalSeparator[0] && this.Text.Contains(decimalSeparator[0]))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyChar == decimalSeparator[0] && this.Text.Length < 1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        try
        {
            Value = Convert.ToDecimal(this.Text);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    protected override void OnValidated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnValidated(e);

        try
        {
            // format the value as currency
            decimal dTmp = Convert.ToDecimal(this.Text);
            this.Text = dTmp.ToString("C");
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public decimal Value
    {
        get { return this._value; }
        set { this._value = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping all your original code, I changed two things and everything seems to work nicely:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnTextChanged(e);

  try
  {
    this._value = Convert.ToDecimal(this.Text); // Assign private field instead of property, due to the next change.
  }
  catch { }
}

public decimal Value
{
  get { return this._value; }
  set 
  { 
    this._value = value;
    this.Text = this._value.ToString("C"); // Set the text when Value is set.
  }
}
```

Then your usage is as simple as:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  currencyTextBox1.Value = 20000;
}
```

Comment: Great...this is what I'm looking for. I have already set `this.Text` on `Value` properties but in the `KeyPress` event I set `Value` instead of `_value`. Thank you @OhBeWise, this help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `textChanged` event, so when you assign a value the format is applied.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = "20000";
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormatText();
        }

        private void FormatText()
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)) // Validate input
                return; 
            decimal amount;
            Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out amount);
            if (amount == 0) // Validate if it's a number
                return;
            textBox1.Text = "$" + String.Format("{0:n0}",amount); // Format with no decimals
            textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0); // Set the cursor position to last character
        }
```

Comment: I have used `TextChanged` event in `CurrencyTextBox` code. In the `Form1_Load` event, I have assigned the `CurrencyTextBox` like this `currencyTextBox1.Text = 20000`, but when I run the project it doesn't format the value into $20.000,00

Comment: Put the formatting code on a method, when you assign the value onload/constructor call the formatting method, and put the method inside your event too

Comment: Do you mean, after assigned the value to CurrencyTextBox, I should call the formatting method? It takes 2 steps, what I want is it also displayed in the currency formatted when I assigned a value.

Comment: Yes, that's why you are making a method, so your code isn't duplicated and you call it on load and on keypress/textchanged

Comment: If I put formatting code in `TextChanged` event, when the cursor enter the CurrencyTextBox it will be displayed in currency format ($20,000.00) instead of decimal (20000). Could you give the example code to explain your answer?

Comment: Thanks @kondas, I really appreciate your help, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The simple `TextBox` doesn't have property where you can set the currency format. but, there are some approaches that you can use to format the TextBox text into proper format.

1) Create a custom control and inherit the TextBox where you can override the `TextBox`'s `Text` property and make your changes.

```
public shadow string Text
{
    get{
        return base.Text.Replace("$", "").Replace(",","");
    }
    set{
        base.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString("C");
    }
}
```

2) If you dont want to create custom control then you can define a property in your form and use that property instead of TextBox's Text property.

```
public shadow string AmountText
{
    get{
        return txtAmount.Text.Replace("$", "").Replace(",","");
    }
    set{
        txtAmount.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString("C");
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** This is just to create idea. You need to modify the code to return and set the value properly.